# Php&MySQL Matchmaking Algorithm With Score

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, match, matching

i'm thinking how can i matchmaking with PHP and MySQL but I can not find.

For example we have a mysql users table and users set some setting their profiles and we macth profiles with percentage.

Our simple mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` enum('M','F') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
  `answer1` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer2` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer3` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer4` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer5` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer6` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer7` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer8` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer9` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  `answer10` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `gender` (`gender`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And our rows:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `gender`, `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `answer5`, `answer6`, `answer7`, `answer8`, `answer9`, `answer10`) VALUES
(1, 'maleuser1', '123456', 'male1@male1.com', 'M', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'),
(2, 'maleuser2', '123456', 'male2@male2.com', 'M', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'),
(3, 'femaleuser1', '123456', 'female1@female1.com', 'F', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'),
(4, 'femaleuser2', '123456', 'female2@female2.com', 'F', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y');
```

You can see we have 2 male and 2 female users (normally they will be thousands) and I want to search best matching female profiles for male profiles with percentage.

For example we will query:

```
select username, blabla as percentage 
from users where gender = 'F' 
and ("here best matchmaking codes") 
and we show users; femaleuser1 and you matching %85.
```

And we will only showing matcing bigger than percentage %70.

So i'm talking for that but I can not solve.

Comment: Are you planning to compare each answer only with the other answers of the same number? Meaning, you want to compare answer1 with answer1, answer2 with answer2, etc, but not answer1 with any other answer.

Comment: I'm planning to compare for answer1 with answer1, answer2 with answer2.

For example;

Question1 = Do you like Apple ?
Male user answer1 = Yes
Female user answer1 = No

İf male user's answer1 = femaleuser's answer1, this two profile will match for this question.

Forexample: 

answers - male user answers - female user answers
answer1 - Yes - Yes
answer2 - No - No
answer3 - Yes - Yes
answer4 - Yes - Yes
answer5 - Yes - No

For this example profile match percentage is %80, because only answer5 didn't match, but others answers were match.

Comment: have you got solution? i am also looking for same solution please let me know if you get a solution

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot compare apples with orange. You can look for assignment and maximize workers and jobs. In your problem description it would be maximize female and male pairs. Look for hungarian algorithm or edmonds v blossom algorithm.